# Error after submitted sitemap on Google Search console status show couldn't fetch (HTTP error 403)

Tags: wordpress, blogger, sitemap, google-search-console

Consider:

[image]

I got a sitemap error on the Google Search console, while previously after submitting it was not an error of the sitemap couldn't fetch. I removed the sitemap and submitted again, but the issue remained as it was. I tried a lot to find the solution on the Internet how to resolve this issue, but it did not help me. Such as:

1. Edit [.htaccess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) to force to have *sitemap.xml* instead of *sitemap.php*
2. Check if search engine visibility is unchecked ([WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress))
3. Check if the permalink a set well
4. Check if sitemap URL are submitted correctly
5. I removed all sitemap URLs and submitted it again.
6. Check if *robots.txt* blocks the sitemap URL and add them to the *robots.txt* file

I would like to see all sitemap URLs submitted on Google Search console to have a status of "success", not "couldn't fetch". All methods are mentioned above I already tried them and they did not help me to resolve the issue. I am using a WordPress site and rankmath (all sitemaps are generated by rankmath). How can I fix this?

Comment: Re *"rankmath"*: Do you mean *[Rank Math](https://wordpress.org/plugins/seo-by-rank-math/)*?

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue once, then I did a few steps and within 48 hours all the errors were fixed. (IN WORDPRESS)

1. Delete all created sitemaps.
2. Reinstalled the SitKit and Rankmath Plugins
3. Checked for any updates in WordPress and plugins
4. The open rank math plugin and go to settings -> Sitemaps
5. There you will find all the links to the sitemap.
6. Just turn on the necessary options
7. Copy and paste them and submit them to the Google Search console